# Setting the "Protected content" setting

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

When watching videos from certain sites inside the Chrome browser, the videos will only play when the "Allow identifiers for protected content" setting is checked (Settings -> Content settings... -> Protected content).  I've created a simple c# winforms app with a cefsharp browser control.  When I navigate to the video URL, I receive the same error as when the "Allow identifiers for protected content" setting is unchecked in Chrome.  How do I enable this setting in cefsharp?  I can't find any documentation related to this setting anywhere.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the websites your trying to watch videos from require `Proprietary codecs` like `h264`? If so then `CefSharp` does not support those due to licensing restrictions, you can search `cefsharp proprietary codec` to find out more.

Comment: It does not.  It's the XFinity online streaming site.  I can watch ESPN no problem with the cefsharp browser, but not HGTV.  The Flash error code is the same on cefsharp as what is displayed in Chrome when the setting is unchecked.

Comment: Just be aware that their are many sites you won't be able to watch. As for the setting, you need to track down either a command line option for it or dig through the `Chromium` source to see which `Preference` is being set when you check that option. You maybe better off asking on http://www.magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php as someone their may have used that option. `CefSharp` is just a wrapper around `CEF`.